# how to export GridView To Excel? sharepoint2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, sharepoint

I have the following code:

this is my button: `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export" />`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string attachment = string.Empty;
        attachment = "attachment; filename=ReportName" + ".xls"; //Setting the attachment name.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();//clears all content output from the buffer stream.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType ="application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
        htw.WriteLine("<center><b><u><font size='5'> " + attachment + " </font></u></b></center>");//will be displayed in excel as a heading.
        GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);           
        frm.Controls.Add(GridView1);
        frm.RenderControl(htw);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

but when I click the button only page is being refreshed and nothing else happens, Please help me

I am not able to use this method:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
//base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Clear();

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;
filename=FileName.xls");


Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

Response.End();

}
```

Comment: same problem it is not woring

Comment: try adding breakpoint in the code. tell me what u get in stringwrite?